# Adding event listener to FontAwesome icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I'm currently trying to make a media player that is OOP. A requirement is that I make custom media player buttons, and not use the ones inherent within the audio object. I've pulled icons from Font Awesome, and am having trouble giving them eventlisteners.

I put the icons into a span class called clickable

```
<span class="clickable">
<span class="fa fa-backward fa-4x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" id="Back"></span>
<span class="fa fa-pause fa-4x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" id="Pause"></span>
<span class="fa fa-play fa-4x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" id="Play"></span>
<span class="fa fa-forward fa-4x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" id="Forward"></span>
</span>
```

Then in the CSS I made the #clickable class clickable

```
  #clickable {
  cursor:pointer;
  }
```

Then in the JS added an eventListener that does not detect anything.Right now I'm just having it log hello to see if the function executes, but ultimately I want to call an object method.

```
document.getElementById('Back').addEventListener("click", 
function(e){
  e.preventDefault
  console.log(hello);
  // myPlaylist.play();
})
```

Comment: I think there is a Logical Error. `preventDefault` is a function not a property then you should call it like that `e.preventDefault()` . and I don't know if you have `hello` variable or you want to print "hello".

Comment: It's working fine, but is erroring `hello is not defined` because "hello" should be wrapped in quotes to treat it as a string. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgyEGw

Comment: PS. your  `#clickable` CSS definition is for an `id` _not_ a class. You should change this to `.clickable`

Answer (score 1):

To put in code what other people already pointed out in comments:

Change the css, using class instead of id:

```
  .clickable {
     cursor:pointer;
  }
```

or, as i personally suggest, make the cursor a pointer only for the span inside:

```
.clickable span {
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

Change your javascript, fixing a missing variable hello and using preventdefault as a function.

```
document.getElementById('Back').addEventListener("click", 
function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('hello');
  // myPlaylist.play();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but in my case addEventListener does not see an awesome icon either.
I ended up at setting  a custom attribute ('data-index', index) to font-awsome class variable.

```
icon.setAttribute('data-index', 1)

icon.addEventListener('click', e => {
a=e.target.getAttribute('data-index')
if a=1 {
console.log('hello')
}
```